# Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component while using useDispatch

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am using `useDispatch` hook because of which I am getting an invalid hook call error. Please have a look and let me know where I am going wrong.

```
export default function SocialLogin() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  function handleSocialLogin(provider) {
    dispatch(closeModal());
    SocialLogin(provider);
  }

  return (
    <>
        <Button
            onClick={() => handleSocialLogin('facebook')}
            icon='facebook'
            fluid
            color='facebook'
            style={{ marginBottom: 10 }}
            content='Login with Facebook'
        />
        <Button
            onClick={() => handleSocialLogin('google')}
            icon='google'
            fluid
            color='google plus'
            content='Login with Google'
        />
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Have a look at this: https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks

You can't use dispatch(closeModal()) inside a function, other than a component function. You should surround it with useCallback().

Comment: what's the `SocialLogin(provider)` in `handleSocialLogin`??

the 'SocialLogin' overlaps with the name of the current function component, so i think it could be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was SocialLogin is another function written for calling different sign-in methods and since the name of current function is also SocialLogin the system was not calling the right function